# Can't manage to fetch response (React)

Tags: reactjs, response, fetch

I Have tried various combinations of this, and none works. Any idea?

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    let newsletter = 'https://domain.us0.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=00000&id=00000';
    let email = '&EMAIL=' + this.state.value;
    fetch(newsletter + email, {
      mode: 'no-cors',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json().then(data => this.setState({message: data.msg}));
    });
    console.log(this.state.message);
    console.log(this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at App.js:35
    at <anonymous>
```

In the network tab, everything looks right. I'm getting the following response:

```
{"result":"error","msg":"user@gmail.com is already subscribed to list."}
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Did you check the chrome dev network tab?

Comment: Hi! I updated above

Comment: There is something wrong with response data converting to json, check using: `return response.text().then(function(text) {
    return text ? JSON.parse(text) : {}
  })`

Answer (score 0):

I would structure and use Promises differently, you can simply do as follows and make your code more readable:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let newsletter = 'https://domain.us0.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=00000&id=00000';
  let email = `&EMAIL=${this.state.value}`;

  fetch(`${newsletter}${email}`, { method: 'GET', mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Here you can also handle errors
      if (data.result === 'error') {
        // Handle Error
      } else {
        this.setState({ message: data.msg });
      }

      console.log(this.state.message);
      console.log(this.state.value);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  // Keep in mind that these console statements might
  // execute before your Promise is resolved, thus
  // referring to the state before the request
  // has been fulfilled. For this reason I commented them out
  // console.log(this.state.message);
  // console.log(this.state.value);
}
```

I noticed you used a mixture of `function` and `=>`, so I would suggest to pick one of the two unless you have a specific reason to use one or the other.

I fear that the fact that you use `function` the first time creates a new context so that `this` now refers to whatever `this` is inside the function where you convert to `json`, since you don't want to create a new context in this scenario, stick with arrow functions.

This is the kind of approach I usually follow when handling AJAX requests, since the first `.then` is returning a `Promise` you can chain another `.then` that will work on the result of the previous one. It's easier to read and to debug.